Error when printing map title with ol-ext print dialog Openlayers
I'm using the ol-ext print dialog to enable printing with Openlayers. There was no option to type the map title.
So I added the code:
// Add a title control
map.addControl(new ol.control.CanvasTitle({ 
  title: 'my title', 
  visible: false,
  style: new ol.style.Style({ text: new ol.style.Text({ font: '20px "Lucida Grande",Verdana,Geneva,Lucida,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif'}) })
}));

After this update, I was no longer able to generate PDF and it shows the error:"Can't save map canvas..."
Complete code follows.
// Print control
var printControl = new ol.control.PrintDialog({ 
});
printControl.setSize('A4');
map.addControl(printControl);

/* On print > save image file */
printControl.on(['print', 'error'], function(e) {
  // Print success
  if (e.image) {
    if (e.pdf) {
      // Export pdf using the print info
      var pdf = new jsPDF({
        orientation: e.print.orientation,
        unit: e.print.unit,
        format: e.print.size
      });
      pdf.addImage(e.image, 'JPEG', e.print.position[0], e.print.position[0], e.print.imageWidth, e.print.imageHeight);
      pdf.save(e.print.legend ? 'legend.pdf' : 'map.pdf');
    } else  {
      // Save image as file
      e.canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        var name = (e.print.legend ? 'legend.' : 'map.')+e.imageType.replace('image/','');
        saveAs(blob, name);
      }, e.imageType, e.quality);
    }
  } else {
    console.warn('No canvas to export');
  }
});

Does anyone know what it could be?
// Add a title control
map.addControl(new ol.control.CanvasTitle({ 
  title: 'my title', 
  visible: false,
  style: new ol.style.Style({ text: new ol.style.Text({ font: '20px "Lucida Grande",Verdana,Geneva,Lucida,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif'}) })
}));


Could this be related to CORS issues? Are you loading any external resources such as tiles, fonts, or images? also, what exactly do you mean by "after this update" like ol or  the ol-ext lib?

The update I say is about the code to include the map title, which refers to the code "
map.addControl(new ol.control.CanvasTitle({    title: 'my title',    visible: false, }));
Before this code, I was running the code, exporting to pdf, now, when I click to export, it shows the error.
